How can I assign a library's sass variable without it having a !default value
We have to use a library with some css that looks like this. Until now we imported it with @import, but we'd like to update to @use.
.esri-view {
  ...
  font-family: $font-family;

The $font-family variable doesn't have a default value. Because of this, our @use doesn't work:
@use '@arcgis/core/assets/esri/themes/base/_View.scss' with (
  $font-family: var(--our-internal-font-family)
);

The error:

✘ [ERROR] Undefined variable. font-family: $font-family;

This would be easily fixable with a $font-family: somefont !default; in the library's code (as per the sass docs) but as the css is loaded from npm we can't/don't want to change it.
Are there any feasible workarounds for this?
Context: We use this in an Angular 18 setup.

You can create a custom wrapper Sass file that defines the $font-family variable before importing the library. For example:
// _custom-view.scss
$font-family: var(--our-internal-font-family);

@use '@arcgis/core/assets/esri/themes/base/_View.scss' with (
   $font-family: $font-family
);

Then, import your custom wrapper file in your project:
@use './path/to/_custom-view';

This method works by ensuring the variable is already defined when the library's styles are loaded.

This is exactly what I tried but couldn't get working. As far as I understand from the docs (see the link in the original question), this only works if the $font-family variable is defined in the external stylesheet with a !default marker (which it doesn't in my case).
